# Haskell get a specific user's home directory path

Tags: haskell, tilde-expansion

I want to make a function to expand names of the form `~user` with that user's home directory (usually `/home/user/`), including `~root`, which is typically `/root/`. I know of the `getHomeDirectory` method, to get the current user's home, but I don't know of any function to determine the home directory of a given user.

### So far

I have the following function, which replaces a leading `~` in any file path with the user's home directory

```
-- join path with '/', except at root
-- opposite of breakPath
rejoinPath :: [FilePath] -> FilePath
rejoinPath []   = ""
rejoinPath (p:ps)
    | p == "/"  =  p ++ go ps
    | otherwise =  go (p:ps)
    where
        go :: [FilePath] -> FilePath
        go []     = ""
        go [p]    = p
        go (p:ps) = p ++ "/" ++ go ps

-- split path on '/', erasing separator except at root
-- opposite of rejoinPath
breakPath :: FilePath -> [FilePath]
breakPath []    = []
breakPath (c:cs)
    | c == '/'  = "/" : go "" cs
    | otherwise = go [c] cs
    where
        go :: FilePath -> FilePath -> [FilePath]
        go z []         = [z]
        go z (c:cs)
            | c == '/'  = z : go "" cs
            | otherwise = go (z ++ [c]) cs

expandHome :: FilePath -> IO FilePath
expandHome p = rejoinPath <$> (go $ breakPath p)
    where
        go []           = pure []
        go (p:ps)
            | p == "~"  = do 
                            home <- getHomeDirectory
                            pure $ home : ps
            | otherwise = pure $ p : ps
```

My understanding is that the `getHomeDirectory` reads from the `HOME` environment variable, and that the other home directories would be considerably harder to procure, but not impossible or prohibitively difficult I hope.

### Note

I'm only interested in linux systems at the moment; I understand Windows and Mac have entirely different styles.

Comment: Your standard Linux distribution lists the accounts and the corresponding home folders in `/etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is available in the [unix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.1) package using [getUserEntryForName](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.1/docs/System-Posix-User.html#v:getUserEntryForName) and then the `homeDirectory` field of `UserEntry`.

```
import System.Posix.User

main :: IO ()
main = do entry <- getUserEntryForName "djf"
          putStrLn (homeDirectory entry)
```